# Error: W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lt@ad6f640

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am getting this error after 3-4 seconds of app start, even if I changed nothing in the code part of application. And the application freezes. Why? Can someone tell?

```
W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lt@ad6f640
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1029)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1808)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:551)
        at cg.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202414035@20.24.14 (020700-0):1)
        at cg.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202414035@20.24.14 (020700-0):6)
        at lu.A(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202414035@20.24.14 (020700-0):10)
        at lf.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202414035@20.24.14 (020700-0):3)
        at dz.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202414035@20.24.14 (020700-0):3)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at ja.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@202414035@20.24.14 (020700-0):6)
```

Meanwhile, when I click and open file (`ContextWrapper.java:551`), the file has full of red lines inside it, and when I look at imports, these lines are red, giving explanations of 'Cannot resolve symbol SystemApi', 'Cannot resolve symbol TestApi' ... etc. for the below lines.

```
import android.annotation.SystemApi;
import android.annotation.TestApi;
import android.annotation.UnsupportedAppUsage;
import android.app.IApplicationThread;
import android.app.IServiceConnection;
import android.view.DisplayAdjustments;
import android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.AutofillClient;
```

Comment: For reference: It seems like there is a GitHub issue for this problem. Check here:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2284
Also
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4090